# XAML Grid Layout extending beyond viewport

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I am building a mobile layout using the Xamarin platform, where I am writing the UI in XAML. I would like 4 evenly spaced icons along the bottom of my screen. My penultimate row height is defined as a `*`, so this should ensure the screen is filled. The bottom row is `40px`, however, my icons are extending beyond the viewport, so cannot be seen. Why is this happening?

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="70" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="110" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- 12 equally spaced columns -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image  x:Name="BluetoothIcon"
                Source="bluetoothg.png"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

        <!-- 3 other icons defined as above with different column references -->
  </Grid>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: what's the height of your window? sounds like it is exceeding the height of the entire window.

Comment: @mrsargent I don't think I am, if I change the penultimate row (defined as `*` height), to auto, then everything moves up quite a bit and fits on the screen without an inch below the icons.

Comment: How big are your icons after they are displayed on the screen? You may want to try adding `Aspect="AspectFill"` or `Aspect="AspectFit"` to the icons to make them fit in the 40px row. You may also need to try using `VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"`